# Can FBX file Contain a Virus like the alc Virus in 3ds max files?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, fbx

I just heard that 3ds max files can have a virus injected in them called ALC Script Virus
but what about FBX Files ?
the reason im asking is because sometimes im downloading some free 3d models people put on some website for free to use them in blender unity3d and after effects but im Not sure if these fbx files Can contain a Virus inside them like the alc virus in 3ds max files ?

Answer (score 1):

**Simply said no they can't**, there isn't anything executable in them so you should be fine downloading free FBX Files from the internet.

The only thing that could include a virus is if you download a .zip that has a .fbx in it (as well as theoretically other malware).

Comment: Thank you , but also 3ds max Files are also Not executable and they can be injected with ALC Virus ?

Comment: The virus a 3rd-party MaxScript can accidentally corrupt 3Ds Max software's settings and be propagated to other Max files (*.max) on a Windows system if scene files containing the broken script are loaded into 3Ds Max. (The original script seems to have been included with some free 3ds Max scenes that users may have downloaded from various online sources.)